# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sqrt{x^{2}+5x} - x \right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I am being asked to work out:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sqrt{x^{2}+5x} - x \Big)$$

My thinking is -- *OK, so $x$ is some very big **positive** No, so I can rewrite as*
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sqrt{x^{2}+5x} - \sqrt{x^{2}} \Big)$$

I can see that $5x$ will ensure that I approach infinity.

However the actual answer is to use Taylor series approximation around zero (which in itself seems questionable, considering $x$ is approaching infinity) to arrive at an answer of $2.5$.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking. Am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expand around $0$ by substituting $x = \frac{1}{h}$.

For a different approach, note that the limit is equal to $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left(\sqrt{1+5h}-1\right)$$
which is manifestly $f'(0)$ where $f(x) = \sqrt{1+5x}$.

By the chain rule, $f'(x) = \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{1+5x}}$, so $f'(0) = \frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: A different way is to rationalise the numerator:
$$\sqrt{x^2+5x}-x=\dfrac{5x}{\sqrt{x^2+5x}+x}=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Big( \sqrt{x^{2}+5x} - x \Big)=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5x}+x}.$$
Now, if you mean $x\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+5x}+x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{5}{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}+1}=\frac{5}{1+1}=\frac{5}{2}.$$
Also, if you mean $x\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, so the limit does not exist because
$$\lim_{x-\rightarrow-\infty}(\sqrt{x^{2}+5x}-x)=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 5x} - x = x \left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{5}{x}} - 1 \right) = \frac{5}{2} + o\left( 1\right)$$

So the limit is $\frac{5}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x^2+ax}-x
&=(\sqrt{x^2+ax}-x)\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+x}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+ax-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+x}\\
&=\dfrac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+ax}+x}\\
&\to\dfrac{ax}{2x}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Alternative proof.

$\begin{array}\\
(x+a/2)^2
&=x^2+ax+a^2/4\\
&\gt x^2+ax\\
\end{array}
$

so
$x+a/2
\gt \sqrt{x^2+ax}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
(x+a/2-a^2/8x)^2
&=x^2+ax-a^3/(8x)+a^4/(64x^2)\\
&=x^2+ax-(a^3/(8x))(1-a/(8x))\\
&\lt x^2+ax
\qquad\text{for } x > a/8\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for $x > a/8$,

so
$x+a/2
\gt \sqrt{x^2+ax}
\gt x+a/2-a^2/8x
$

or
$0
\gt \sqrt{x^2+ax}-(x+a/2)
\gt -a^2/8x
$.